# What type of loop would I wrap around this statement?

Tags: c++

For some reason I'm getting extremely confused as to what type of loop I should be wrapping around this switch statement. If I have the switch statement below and I want the user to be able to keep inputting a keystroke until it hits one of the cases which type of loop is best to use for this?

Thanks,

```
int input;

cin >> input;

    switch( input )
{
    case 1:
        playgame();
        break;
    case 2:
        loadgame();
        break;
    case 3:
        Multiplayer();
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "Thanks, exitting now \n";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "error \n";
        cin >> input;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Any loop will do. They're esentially the same. Since you want the user to choose __at least once__, a `do while` would be probably logically best, but you can make the code work with `for` and `while` too.

Comment: From what you describe, an infinite loop seems to fit: while (true) { ... }

Comment: I tried the while(true) and for some reason when I do this and hit '4' it doesn't print out "Thanks, exitting now \n".

Comment: Pawel, I thought exactly the same thing. The do-while loop made most logical sense to me as I would always be executing this code at least once. Perhaps it's the condition I'm using, what condition would you suggest at the end of the do-while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is missing some stop condition.

```
int input = 0; // make a habit of initialising all variables
bool again = true;
while(again) { // could use input != 4 (stop value)
cin >> input;

...
case 4: // magic numbers are bad, maybe use enum for the cases.
    cout << "Thanks, exiting now \n";
    again = false; // <----- else you wont get out.
    break;
...
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see exactly what you mean now.. It's working. Thanks for your help Surt.

Comment: If I had initialised input to 0 in the first place I think I would have been able to resolve this. As such, a good point and good lesson has been learnt.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a do while loop because you can ensure that the loop was executed at least 1 full time before exiting. Also, since you don't know how many times the user might iterate through the loop, a For loop is not appropriate.